# Passing Javascript string variable as Firebug command

Tags: javascript, dom, firebug

Using Firebug I have extracted all the links of a web page using:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    console.log(links[i].href);
}
```

now all the links are in the console and they are in the format:

```
javascript:tenderLog1('abcd.pdf','test','23');
```

Now I want to pass this string output as a Firebug js command so that all the links get opened automatically.

Is there any function to pass js variable as a Firebug command?

Comment: You should probably explain your underlying intention, as what you describe you want to accomplish does not make much sense.

Comment: i mean lets say i got the string javascript:tenderLog1('abcd.pdf','test','23');
from the webpage. Now i need to pass this string as a firebug command so that the respective tenderLog1 function is called

Comment: If there is no such command, can u please tell me the regular expression so that i can get the 3 arguments from the string. From there i can call the function manually. Thanks

Comment: @SuryaKLSV The easiest solution is to define a function `tenderLog1`, and use `eval` on that string. Another method is (NO REGEXES!) to get the contents within the parentheses, wrap it in `[`, `]`, and use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: `javascript:tenderLog1('abcd.pdf','test','23');` is not a "firebug command", whatever that would be, so there would not be a way to "pass it" as such. It is an URL. It really makes no sense; you can open URLs using `window.open`, though I think some browsers restrict `javascript:` URLs nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to guess what exactly you want to achieve. I guess that you want instead of

```
console.log(links[i].href);
```

to do

```
eval(links[i].href.replace("javascript:",""));
```

? This would be equivalent to invoking `tenderLog1('abcd.pdf','test','23')` from Firebug console in the example you've provided. The outcome depends on what `tenderLog1` functions does of course.

But perhaps it would be cleaner to see what the function does (`window.open`?), and provide commands after parsing the parameters with some regular expression.